# Which approach of saving model property is better?

Tags: php, oop, cakephp

I have a model *Order* (the model how it looks in [CakePhp](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models.html#models)), which has a property *status*. This property changed while *Order* goes through processing steps. Currently status changing works in this way:

I have related model *OrderStatus*, where I have a set of possible statuses, like

```
<?php
OrderStatus::STARTED
...
OrderStatus::PAID
...
OrderStatus::PROCESSED
```

in *Order* model I have a method to change *status*:

```
<?php
/**
 * Save new status value for Order.
 *  
 * @param  int $id Order id
 * @param  int $status   New status value
 * @param  int $current  [Optional] Current status value
 * @return boolean
 */
public function changeStatus($id, $status, $current = null) {
    // some code
}
```

and when I need to change it somewhere in Controller, or another model I just call it like:

```
<?php
$Order->changeStatus($id, OrderStatus::PAID);
```

So far everything works fine with this solution, but now I'm thinking how correct this approach is. What if tomorrow I'll decide to do some additional actions on specific status changing, so I have to add some additional logic and extend changeStatus method. Also what I don't really like is that I have to use *OrderStatus* constants everywhere I need to change order status, so it spreads throughout code.

Isn't more correct to add separate methods to set each new status, use *OrderStatus* constans within these methods and put all related logic there too, and change statuses outside *Order* model in a way like:

```
<?php
$Order->makePaid($id);
// and 
$Order->makeProcessed($id);
```

Which one is better from OOP principles and best practices perspective, or maybe there is another better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, what you and most of the "MVC" (notice it is in quotes because they are not actually MVC, but more like trying to imitate the pattern but they are not) frameworks call "model" is an entity with business logic in one. In most cases they are using Active Record pattern as well to be able to represent the links in the DB in a more abstract way.

As it comes to your question, first of all, it is wrong from the perspective of the "controller" (in quotes again because it is not exactly a controller, since it does much more) to be involved that much with the entity itself. It is much better that there is a "Service" layer which abstracts what you want to do which is being called by the "controller" and the "Service" itself knows how to handle those requests. What I am trying to say is that the controller only relays the events.

In your case there should be something like `OrdersService` which keeps the logic for orders. For example: making a new one, paying such order, etc. The controller makes an instance of the `OrdersService` and calls `$ordersService->createOrder($requiredData)` or `$ordersService->processOrder($id)`. Then the `OrdersService` on the other hand calls the Order "model" to process such events separately. The more separation of logic you have in different classes, the better. Usually many people try to follow the logic of the frameworks and end up with massive God classes having too much logic inside of them.

Please consider reading [SOLID Principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) and [Separation Of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) if you want to start using better OOP practices in general.

Comment: thanks ziGi, indeed you are right about CakePhp "model", and it's already became a "God class" in my app. I think often and often about Service layer. But I see it not as 1:1 for Entity:Service, but plan to create services for some specific purpose, so in theory I could end up with entity Order and services like InitOrderService, OrderPaymentService, OrderConfirmation service etc. But still not sure how correct it will be, could you look please on my another question about this http://stackoverflow.com/q/27453188/483204

Answer (score 1):

I suggest Order object should represent a single order (single id) with methods relating to operations that can be done on the order. This should make sense to the problem your application is trying to solve. So if an order needs to be paid why not have a `pay()` method; side effect of which can be setting the right current status. Similarly for start and process.

```
class Order {

    private $id;
    private $currentStatus;

    //other methods...

    public function pay(Money $payment) {
        //handle payment etc.
        $this->currentStatus = OrderStatus::PAID;
    }

    public function start() {
        //do business logic related to starting an order.
        $this->currentStatus = OrderStatus::STARTED;
    }

    public function process() {
        //process an order
        $this->currentStatus = OrderStatus::PROCESSED;
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer Nik, and I like this approach, but in my app I really need sometimes to change item status from outside. Maybe it means that I have architecture problems deeper.

Comment: nothing wrong with `changeStatus($status)` method an Order object needs to have it

Answer (score 1):

In "Clean code" Robert C. Martin adviced that the less arguments the better. Its better to create dedicated method for given action than generic one with plenty of arguments. That way your code will be more expressive for readers.

In your example if you create dedicated method for each action which changes status, change of the status itself will became an implementation detail of order object and will not be exposed outside the object. Its a big advantage because you can change it and order dependent classes won't need any change.

Comment: thanks for your opinion and arguments for dedicated methods, looks convincingly